# How do I use the NotificationCenter UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification to reload my RSS Feed

Tags: ios, rss

I've created a app that loads data from a XML feed file on my server. This works fine but I want it to refresh if the home button is pressed. I know that I need to use the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotfication notif but I can't seem to get it to reload the feed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the class which has the Reloading Methods, you need to add an Observer during init (or wherever you want to start observing) to observe for the notification like shown below. You can set a selector which does the reloading, i've used reloadXMLData here but you can change that to whatever.

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Other init code here...

        // Add our Observer
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadXMLData) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
    }
}
```

Also be sure to remove the Observer once your Class is dealloced if you add it during init. If you add it somewhere else, you'll need to remove it otherwise if your class is dealloced and the observer is still active, your app will crash

```
- (void)dealloc {
    // Other dealloc code here...

    // Remove our Observer
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Now every time the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification is fired, the reloadXMLData method will be called as long as your class is active.